# Any examples of a nice hand rig? Specially fingers

Tags: rigging, add-on

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I'd like to know if there are any good examples of a hand rig with good fingers deformations. I see many muscle deformation systems, but can't really apply them to the fingers. Some real-life examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to achieve cannot be nicely made in blender yet. The problem is mesh intersecting. You need to simulate mesh self-collision to get the bulging result you want. This can be done with soft-bodies but would be unusable for animating.

The best you can do is to make ton of corrective shape keys for your mesh. If you are aiming for super-real you can also add some wrinkle displacement maps and drive them with bones.

Comment: How about mesh cages and lattices? Simple forms are easier to put in the form you need, theoretically though...

Comment: @Vitaliy Well lattices or mesh_deform will not help you with realism much - sculpted shape keys or wrinkle maps will do better. Plus of lattices is that you will have to move less vertices for the shape keys but it is more suitable for cartoon characters. You can also mix them - lattices and wrinkle maps for example.

Answer (score 3):

As Jerryno said there isn't really a good way to do this, however, on twitter [Ton mentioned the Blender Foundation would try to add this](https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/339673537906356224):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHySGIqEgyk

Which is exactly what you need.

see more:

http://rodolphe-vaillant.fr/permalinks/elastic_implicit_skinning_project.php

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it already, great stuff, but my goal is to learn simple approximates and not some hi-tech ways that will, probably, someday come to us. Thanks though.